# Discord.py Trying to get a file per command

Tags: python, pip, discord, discord.py, command

I'm trying to make a bot with a command wich can be triggered by a user to send a file. I managed to get it working, but now it's says everytime i launch the bot, that: This client already has an associated command tree. Maybe someone can help me with that, if there is a old, is there a command to delete it on startup of the bot?

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)

commandTree = discord.app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@commandTree.command(name="command", description="Some command")
async def upload(ctx, *, file: discord.File = None):
    if not file:
        await ctx.send("You didn't include a file.")
    else:
        await file.save(f"uploads/{file.filename}")
        await ctx.send(f"File '{file.filename}' uploaded successfully.")
```

The error:

`discord.errors.ClientException: This client already has an associated command tree.`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong grammar, i'm not an english pro...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdiscord.py%5D+discord.errors.ClientException%3A+This+client+already+has+an+associated+command+tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `client` variable already have a command Tree. You can just use it without redefine another one.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)

# commandTree = discord.app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.tree.command(name="command", description="Some command")
async def upload(ctx, *, file: discord.File = None):
    if not file:
        await ctx.send("You didn't include a file.")
    else:
        await file.save(f"uploads/{file.filename}")
        await ctx.send(f"File '{file.filename}' uploaded successfully.")
```